# Matlab: How to randomly permute and inverse permute a vector

Tags: matlab, random

I need to implement the following algorithm in Matlab.

1. Suppose `A = [3 4 1 9 5]`
2. permute `A` randomly say, `A = [5 1 4 3 9]`
3. Add 2 to the first two elements: `A = [7 3 4 3 9]`
4. permute A back, `A = [3 4 3 9 7]`

I am using `randperm()` function to permute:

```
index = randperm(numel(A));
A = A(index);
```

But the problem is how to permute it back, after changing array `A` to the first permutation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can actually put the indexing on the left hand side:

```
A(index) = A;
```

;-)

Answer (score 4):

So basically, you just want to add 2 to 2 random elements of the vector `A`. No need to permute, just pick two random indexes. In recent versions of matlab [randperm](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/randperm.html) takes two arguments:

> `p = randperm(n,k)` returns a row vector containing `k` unique integers selected randomly from 1 to `n` inclusive.

So then you can use:

```
idx = randperm(numel(A),2);
A(idx)=A(idx) + 2;
```

On older versions, you can use:

```
idx = randperm(numel(A));
idx = idx(1:2);
A(idx)=A(idx) + 2;
```

Comment: ah!! this too. Matlab is simply awesome

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
 index = randperm(numel(A));
 nums=1:length(A)
 return_index=nums(index)
 temp = A(index);
 temp(1:2)=temp(1:2)+2;
 A(nums)=temp(return_index);
```

Comment: you do know that `nums(index)` is exactly the same as `index` (because `nums=1:length(A)`) right? just as `A(nums)` is exactly the same as `A` itself. This seems overly complex :s